# Operator '>' or '>>' bug from GCC inside requires expression within template argument C++

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20

I'm testing these requirements that compose of two basic operations for `>` or `>>` inside the template argument if these expressions are valid:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct dummy 
    : std::bool_constant<
    requires (const T& a, const T& b) {
     a > b;
     a >> b;
}> {};
```

With Clang, it compiles fine. But with GCC, it gave me these several errors:

```
<source>:7:7: error: expected ';' before '>' token
    7 |      a > b;
      |       ^~
      |       ;
<source>:8:7: error: expected ';' before '>>' token
    8 |      a >> b;
      |       ^~~
      |       ;
```

So, in order to suppress these errors, I have to cover the expressions with parenthesis:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct dummy 
    : std::bool_constant<
    requires (const T& a, const T& b) {
     (a > b);
     (a >> b);
}> {};
```

And now, GCC compiles fine.

Even so, this problem may be similar to the thing with `C<42, sizeof(int) > 4>`, but in this case, operations with `>>` and `>` have been enclosed with **braces** from requires expression `requires (...) { ... }`

Unfortunately, I can't file a bug on GCC because I don't have an account yet nor registered.

Comment: Good job finding a bug. But what do you want from us? Did you apply for a GCC bugzilla account? Wait until you get it, then report it...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, yes

Comment: But... is it a GCC bug, or it's Clang being more smart than the standard mandates? I'm _sure_ there are situations where parenthesizing is necessary exactly to disambiguate templates' `<` vs `operator<`, which is explained somewhere in [C++ Templates - The Complete Guide - Second Edition](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/08/4f/e3/084fe33fb91392903a41e44650b24f78.jpg).

Comment: @Enlico I can't imagine GCC behavior being intended. Even if it was, I would consider it a standard defect.

Comment: As regards the reference in my previous comment, here I clarify: at page 50, right before section 3.4, the example is given that `C<42, sizeof(int) > 4> c;` is invalid whereas `C<42, (sizeof(int) > 4)> c;` is valid. I don't know if this is somehow related to the present case (especially because the book is on C++17, not C++20), but I wanted to point it out, just in case.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat [It is indeed](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#579).

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have found a workaround yourself, but I found if you pull out `requires` expression as a concept, the code will compile too:

```
template<typename T>
concept MyConcept=requires (const T& a, const T& b) {
     a > b;
     a >> b;
};

template <typename T>
struct dummy : std::bool_constant<MyConcept<T>> {};
```

Maybe this is my personal preference, but I think the code written like this increases readability too.